# Why isn't the retrieved description adding to TinyMCE?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

```
function edit_article(id){
        edit_editor();
        var title = $('#' + id + ' #t strong').text();
        var image_url = $('#' + id + ' #img_url').text();
        var description = $('#desc_' +id).html();
        $('#article_title_edited').val(title);
        $('#article_image_edited').val(image_url);
        $('#test').html(description);
        $('#article_description_edited').tinymce.get('article_edited').setContent(description);


    }
    function edit_editor(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea#article_edited',
            height: 380,
            language: 'pl',
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
                'charmap', 'lists', 'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen', 'help', 'wordcount'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | bold italic | bullist numlist | removeformat | help',
            block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Header 1=h1; Header 2=h2',
            content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
            extended_valid_elements : 'b/strong',
            formats: {
                bold: { inline: 'b' }
            },
            entity_encoding: 'raw',
            branding: false
        });
```

I want to display this description in another modal with tinymce, to edit existing article on site, title and img_url are okay. But i have problem with desc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a problem importing data into the description field in a Bootstrap modal through the TinyMCE editor. Earlier things described in the code are imported into the inputs above without any issues, but there is a problem with importing the description that I create and is written in a div.